# laravel Call to a member function welcome() on null

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.1

i want to send mail so i made up a mail class so i can pass user data to send him mail.
here is my code class Mailer.php

```
<?php 
use Mail;
abstract class Mailer{
public function sendTo($user, $subject,$view, $data = [])
{
    Mail::send($view, $data, function($message)
    {
        $message->to($user->email, $user->firstname) 
            ->subject($subject)
            ->from('test@test.com', 'Test');
    });
}
}
```

my class that extend the Mailer class :

```
class UserMailer extends Mailer{

public function welcome(User $user){
    $view = 'emails.welcome';
    $data = [];
    $subject = 'test subject';
    return $this->sendTo($user, $subject, $view, $data);
}
```

i want to call this class from any controller so i can pass user data to send mail but i always got this error Call to a member function welcome() on null : maybe i'm doing something wrong :

```
use App\UserMailer as Mailer ;

class TestController extends Controller
{
protected $mailer;
public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->mailer;
}
public function testMailer()
{
    $this->mailer->welcome()->sendTo(1);
    return 'done';
}
```

I want to send this to user id 1. what is wrong with my code ? thx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that that `$this->mailer` property is null. You expect thai it is autoinjected with IoC mechanism of the framework, but it isn't.

In order to make some class autoinjected by typehinting (like in constructor), you must register that class within IoC container. Like (in yours `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`):

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        ...

        $this->app->bind(\App\Contracts\Mailer::class, \App\MyMailerImplementation::class);

        ...
    }

}
```

Make sure to define `\App\Contracts\Mailer` contract first (just an interface for yours mailer), and ther force yours `Mailer` class implementation to inherit and implement that interface via something like:

```
use App\Contracts\Mailer as MailerContract;

class MyMailerImplementation implements MailerContract {
    ...
}
```

*Note: you can use just `Mailer` instead of `MyMailerImplementation`, just be sure to not mess with namespaces then.*